# StackExchange with Elinks

Tags: browser, javascript, elinks

I use Elinks to browse while I am connected remotely. I am unable to login to stackexchange using my OpenID. I enter the correct URL, and upon submission, I get the "No OpenID endpoint found." text. I am certain that I am entering the correct URL. Has anybody else had any success logging in via elinks? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your elinks have javascript support?

Comment: I was under the impression that it did. However I just did some light googling and came upon [This.](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/looking-for-textbrowser-with-javascript-support-or-elink-javascript-support-751828/) The final post seems to have figured it out. Granted that it is from 2009 I hope that it is still relevant. I'm going to try it when I get home. I don't know how I didn't find that link last night.

Comment: Javascript is now enabled, Just loading the stackexchange site now hits me with a bunch of new errors. It is a bunch of syntax errors saying "$ is not defined" or "Typeerror: c.createElement is not a function" or "JQuery is not defined". All I can find on google is how to get javascript enabled, I am not having any luck finding anybody with the same problem.

Comment: Most likely nobody bothers using elinks with stackexchange. It probably has a half-baked support on the browser end of things. Likely the javascript engine it uses is up to par, but the browser still must support the DOM etc. I don't know if elinks does.

Comment: Well poop. I'll keep messing with it then. I'll post an answer if I ever get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried w3m?

Comment: @FaheemMitha All the sources I found said that w3m does not support javascript. I looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764624/how-can-you-use-javascript-in-terminal-for-w3m) and [this](http://web-browsers.findthebest.com/compare/8-18/w3m-vs-ELinks).

Comment: @Onyx: I was able to log into stackoverflow just now using w3m and openid. You are right that w3m does not support javascript by default, though one of your links mentions some extension. Howevever the login with openid still works (I use myopenid). Your openid provider might require js, dunno.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Oh cool, I'll try when I get home from work in a bit. If it works I will let you know and you should post that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Onyx: Made this into a formal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[w3m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/w3m) works for me when logging into Stack Overflow on the console using MyOpenID. w3m does not support JavaScript by default. However, it seems JavaScript is not necessary for logging into Stack Overflow using OpenID, at least when using MyOpenID.

Comment: I have an OpenID at [myOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com) and after I enter (in Emacs-w3m) my credentials, I get stuck on their page. (Probably, JavaScript is needed. It works in Iceweasel.) What OpenID do you use? Logging in to the SX sites from w3m would be cool :)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg: I used myopenid, as stated in the answer. It worked for me with w3m. Emacs 23.2+1-7 and w3m 0.5.2-9 on Debian squeeze. If nothing happens after you type the credentials, make sure you actually hit what corresponds to the enter key in the page. I recall it was not obvious. Just a random looking square or something.

Comment: I use Debian as well. This is what happens to me: it starts [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/cred.png), and whatever I enter (bogus data or my real OpenID creds, doesn't matter), I get [this](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/result.png). If it is not too much to ask, could you test again? I would really benefit from w3m + SX.